# JavaScript GET to retrieve one variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, javascriptcore

I haven't really written any javascript but am building an iOS application that will utilize JavaScriptCore's framework to read a javascript code to get  a variable. What I'm looking to do is set up a GET (I think) so that I can retrieve JSON data from a url and then pull a specific string from the JSON data. Within the GET method, I'll need to add credentials and one parameter. What is the best practice to do this?

Comment: If the URL you're trying to pull from is third party and does not have CORS headers in the response, or doesn't return data in JSONP format, then what you're trying to do won't be possible. That said, all you need to know to make an AJAX request in jQuery is here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Rory's statement above the server you are requesting the json data from must either be on the same domain as your Application/Js code or support the CORS headers.

If the above is true, then you can either use JQUery as suggested above, or for a more minimalist approach the W3Schools has a tutorial on basic Ajax.

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_httprequest.asp